# LNK 2028 unresolved token & LNK 2019 unresolved extern symbol

Tags: c++, lnk2019

I'm working with VS 2013, using UI forms.
In MyForm.h there is a code

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
private:
};

void b()
{
    A var;
}
```

I get those errors:

```
Error   2   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00000A) "public: __thiscall A::A(void)" (??0A@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl b(void)"
Error   3   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00000B) "public: __thiscall A::~A(void)" (??1A@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl b(void)"
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall A::A(void)" (??0A@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl b(void)"
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall A::~A(void)" (??1A@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl b(void)"
```

I've already googled for about two hours, but, still no result.

Comment: You neither defined the constructor nor destructor. If you want the default definitions, write `= default` after both declarations (before the semicolon).

Comment: Gracias. 
Fell myself stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the constructor and destructor like:

```
class A{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
private:
};
  A::A(){
}
  A::~A(){
}
void b()
{
  A var;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but Columbo already solved it in the comments.
Do you know, by the way,
Can I use a "pair < Type, int>" If "Type" is the template <class Type> ?
compiler says error C2079: 'std::pair<Type,int>::first' uses undefined class 'Type'

Comment: You have to write:
template <class Type> before define each function if you define it outside of the class.

Comment: I mean I have a 
`template <class Type>
class List
{
private:
 list < pair < Type, int > > _list;
 int amount, max_amount, type;
public:
`
It says 'std::pair<Type,int>::first' uses undefined class 'Type'

Comment: I dont know From this. Can you send me the full code somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just don't get can pair<> take an argument, if we've defined it as a template type (like template <class type>).                                                              It doesn't work. Says: 'std::pair<Type,int>::first' uses undefined class 'Type'

Comment: After you define a template you should be able to use anywhere i guess. I dont know, sorry. But make another question.